# Odoo `Permission denied (publickey)`. SSH login to change Odoo proxy mode to true

Tags: nginx, ssh, odoo, openssh, odoo-11

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781785883644/16/ch16lvl1sec138/configure-a-reverse-proxy-and-ssl to install odoo with ssl on digitalocean. Odoo is working without ssl.

Unfortunately, I cannot log in to odoo@myipaddress

Errorcode: `Permission denied (publickey)`.

I have written down all Odoo passwords but I did not do anything else. I used Yenthe666 installscript for Odoo as in https://github.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript. My configuration file is called odoo-server.conf

But I have root access. What can I do to gain access as a odoo user to enable odoo proxy mode. I cannot even see the proxy mode entry as root user.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using `sundo -i -u odoo`? Anyways, setting up and SSL doesn't need to login as odoo, you can do everything using the root user. Just set up the proper NginX configuration then set the proxy_mode to True

Answer (score 0):

Please review following items.

- Generate your public and private keys in your local machine. Now login as root and attached your public key in authorized key folder.
- Now try to login with "ssh -i your_private_key odoo@ipaddress"
- Do you have firewalls rules enable in your DigitalOcean ?
- Type IP address in your browser and it should redirect you "Welcome Nginx" page. If not, then have issue with "nginx" setup.
- Check .ssh key file permission

Comment: well I can login with root also with ssh, but not with odoo user! so maybe .ssh key file permission is wrong, but I dont know how to check that

Comment: logging in as root user via ssh and then sudo su odoo gives me permission denied

Comment: any more ideas I know my admin password, where could I add ssh keys for the single user?

Comment: Upload your public key in server and try to access it private key.